# Обтекание изображения текстом

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток. Возникла необходимость выполнить обтекание изображения (ImageView) текстом (TextView). Немножко погуглив, удалось найти [неплохой класс](http://dev.androidteam.ru/snippets/textview/leadingmarginspan2), решающий мою проблему, ибо стандартными средствами ничего толкового не сделаешь. Но все-таки не все так просто. Если текст не содержит переносов строк, то все в порядке, но у меня в тексте переносов минимум 40. Таким образом, для первых строк все работает как надо, для последующих, содержащих '\n', идет отступ вообще с другого края (по умолчанию с левого, а с переносом строки - с правого). Таким образом, в строке полная каша. Прошу помочь как-то разрулить возникшую ситуацию. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если это все не в listview, то можно использовать webview. Сторонних библиотек не нужно тогда.

Comment: @Deadkenny, к сожалению, все в итоге лежит в ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С двумя TextView можно проще. Т.е. один textview размещаем справа от картинки, второй - под ней. Останется только подобрать высоту, чтоб помещалось четкое количество строк (margin-ом для картинки, например).

```
TextView mFirst = ...
TextView mSecond = ...

mFirst.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) { // API 11
        mFirst.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
      } else {
        mFirst.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
      }
      int h = mFirst.getHeight();
      int lh = mFirst.getLineHeight();
      int maxl = h / lh;
      if (mFirst.getLineCount() > maxl) {
        int i = mFirst.getLayout().getLineStart(maxl);
        String text = (String) mFirst.getText();
        mSecond.setText(text.substring(i));
        mFirst.setText(text.substring(0, (i == 0) ? 0 : i - 1));
      } else {
        mSecond.setText("");
      }
    }
});
```

ЗЫ Код выдран из разных частей проекта, возможны ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо, я что-то похожее пытался вчера написать, но в итоге толком ничего не вышло. Пойду попробую прикрепить к проекту.))
_____
Бедапечаль... getLineCount() == 0, ибо у меня адаптер.(( Нидимо, не судьба.

Comment: @PhoEn-X, пробуйте выполнять код после inflate для view (в getView адаптера), когда размеры уже будут просчитаны.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, а про класс Spannable и его производные не слышали? [Вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494158/how-to-align-textview-around-an-imageview?rq=1) правильный ответ.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, а вы вопрос читали? Ссылка на тот же снипет и дана. Кроме того, по удобству вариант с webView выглядит гораздо интереснее, если уж в коде генерить контент.
____
@PhoEn-X, набросал [гист](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d14a847dee58cf61d29d) с адаптером, все работает.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо, конечно, но я пошел кустарным путем: сложил все отступы, создал точно такой же TextView, задал отступы, получил нужную ширину, задал текст, прочитал позицию, на которой заканчивается нужная строка, а дальше просто отправил это значение в конструктор адаптера)) Таким образом мне удалось сохранить все ранее заданные span'ы (ибо таких у меня в сумме около 50). И у меня почему-то не работало в адаптере, хотя и выполнялся код после задания текста. Но все равно ваш ответ очень помог сделать все с 1 TextView, и все работает. Еще раз Спасибо! Выручили))